# Свайп определенного linearlayout

Tags: android, swipe

Здравствуйте возникла проблема
есть маинактивити с дизайном из 3 плит линеарлайоута
примерно так
[пример](http://i.gyazo.com/1ab7b8ba7e421df1a190bb70c45a8d7f.png)
вот код этой плитки:

```
 <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
   android:gravity="center" 
        android:background="#092E47"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        >
             <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
   android:gravity="center"     
        >
             <ImageView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_margin="5dp"

             android:src="@drawable/contact" />
             </LinearLayout>
             <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
   android:gravity="center" 
   android:orientation="vertical"

        >
              <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="заголовок"
            android:textColor="#D0DFD7"
            android:textSize="18sp"

            android:typeface="normal" />
         <TextView
             android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Новости"
            android:textColor="#D0DFD7"
            android:textSize="16sp"

            android:typeface="normal" />
         </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
```

мне нужно сделать свайп новостей в бок

Comment: Мне нужен именно свайп только на этом линеарлайоут

Answer (score 1):

Немного не понятен вопрос. Если Вам нужен свайп как в приложении Gmail (ну там с дополнительными кнопками по плиткой), то [SwipeListView](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview)